# How to Add Groups to Capture Words from RegEx split pattern?

Tags: regex, keyboard-maestro

I have the following RegEx pattern, which seems to work properly in matching the words in a string, with words separated by a colon (:):

`/"[^"]*"|[^:]+/g`

using [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oZ1qZ3/1)

It properly identifies the words.
But how do I add capture groups that will work with n words?

For example, search of

`10:05:12:00`

should return 4 groups of 

`10
05
12
00`

Ultimately this pattern will be used in a Keyboard Maestro Search Using RegEx Action.

TIA.

Comment: Have you tried any capture groups? Does `/("[^"]*"|[^:]+)/g` work? It seems to on regex101.com

Comment: Thanks. that works perfectly in the regex101.com tool.  Now I just need to figure out how to implement in KM.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really came from @TessellatingHeckler in his/her comment above:

> Have you tried any capture groups? Does `/("[^"]*"|[^:]+)/g` work? It
>   seems to on regex101.com

Best implementation in KM is TBD.

For completeness and future ref, here's a screenshot:

[image]